# Remove char from char* and return char*

Tags: c

I have one char array and I want to delete chars that satisfy my condition. Example I have a char array A={1,-1,0 ,1 ,-1} and I want to delete elements that equal -1. That mean output is {1,0,1}, and I want to check how many element in the array. In my example is 3. Can you help me please?

```
char* delete_char(char* sourceArray, char inputChar)
{

    char* out=NULL;
   //Need to malloc memory. But I don't know how many size will allocate because it depends on how many element that don't equal -1


   return out;
} 
int sizeofArray(char* sourceArray)
{
  return size;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the length of the input array? You don't have either a count or appear to have a delimiting character. If you do need to scan the array to count it then you can rememeber two counts: one for the current count and one for the new value by not counting characters you're about to remove. Or just allocate the new array the same size as the input array if that's easier - you may not remove that many characters.

Answer (score 3):

You have some strategies:

- Calculate the exact size before allocating.
- Estimate a size.
- Allocate a big size memory (you probably know maximum size in worse case).

In two later cases, you can use `realloc` to shrink the memory. In your code, the estimated size is `strlen(sourceArray)+1` if the array is a zero-terminated string, because by deleting the result is less and equal to it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you are using char* as an array, you also need to provide information about the length of that array (how many items it contains). Usualy this is done by a second parameter.

In your case: `delete_char(char *inputArray, char inputArraySize, char inputChar)`.

Then you should allocate your result array to be the size of your input array (because it can contain at most as much items as the input array).

After that, you should iterate through every item in the input array and if the item fulfills your condition, add it into the result array. Of course, you have to provide also the size of the output array (for instance in an another output parameter), so you'll be able to work with it.

And lastly, when your done with working with the resulting array, don't forget do deallocate all of its memory (that means deallocate it as it was the size of the original input array, because it actially is).

Answer (score 1):

You can write own function like that.

```
int size(char *ptr)
{

    int offset = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (*(ptr + offset) != '\0')
    {
        ++count;
        ++offset;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I have char * A=malloc(5*sizeof(char)); for(i=0;i<5;i++){A[i]=rand()%2;}. And output A= {1,-1,0 ,1 ,-1}.And I run your code size(A) or strlen() but it is return 1. What is happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the array to determine the number of elements you are removing, then allocate and appropriate memory, then copy.  For example:

```
int sizeNeeded = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray(sourceArray; i++) {
    if (sourceArray[I] != inputChar) sizeNeeded++;
    } 
char *rv = (char *) malloc(sizeNeeded * sizeOf(char));
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray(sourceArray; i++) {
    if (sourceArray[I] != inputChar) rv[j++] = sourceArray[i];
    }
```

I did not try to compile this code but it should convey the idea

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
#include <string.h>

char* delete_char(char* sourceArray, char inputChar)
{
    int iNr = 0,iSize,j = 0;

    iSize = strlen( sourceArray );

    for( int i = 0; i < iSize; i++ )
    if( sourceArray[i] == inputChar )
    iNr ++;

    char *newarray = new char[iNr +1];

    for( int i = 0; i < iSize; i++ )
    {
        if( sourceArray[i] != inputChar )
        newarray[j++] = sourceArray[i];
    }

   return newarray;
}
int sizeofArray(char* sourceArray)
{
  return strlen( sourceArray );
}
```

PS TESTED. It works but may not be very efficient cause you check it 2 times.

Comment: Thank you every body for reply. I know the size of input array. And I already check with strlen() but it is return 1. What is happend?

Comment: strlen( char_array ) returns the length of an array (multiple chars) which end up with NULL, example: "abcde hj\0" where "\0" means NULL. Here strlen would return 8.If the Null is missing at the end, you may run into trouble.Make sure you give strlen an array!

Comment: BTW If the answer is correct , don't forget to chose it ( set it as being the answer ).

Comment: I have char * A=malloc(5*sizeof(char)); for(i=0;i<5;i++){A[i]=rand()%2;}. And output A= {1,-1,0 ,1 ,-1}.And I run your code strlen(A) but it is return 1. What is happen?

Comment: Maybe if you do: char* A = (char*) malloc(5*sizeof(char));

Comment: Wait, it outputs {1,-1,0 ,1 ,-1} ? hmm maybe strlen doesn't work. There are times when such functions didn't work for me. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @user2938494 There is no way to find the size of the array that pointer `A` is pointing to.